# Mysql query limiting number of items

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: **collections** and **collection_items**.

I'm trying to figure out how can I select for each collection, get a maximum of 4 collection_items in the same query.

Some collections may have more than 4 items, but I only need a maximum 4 to show.

The following query returns all items for every collection but do not know how can I limit it to 4.

```
SELECT  cn.*, o.url_thumb
FROM collection_names as cn LEFT JOIN collection_items as ci ON ci.collection_id=cn.id
     LEFT JOIN objects as o ON o.ID=ci.object_id
WHERE cn.public=1
ORDER BY cn.fecha DESC
LIMIT 0, 20
```

Table definition:
[image]

Comment: which 4 `collection_item` will you like to show?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza I do not mind the order.. may be random.

Comment: LIMIT 0, 20 is a pagination that fetch first 20 collectiones_names

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution utilizing allocation of `group row num` and `sub-query`.

```
select id, user_id, image_object_id, name, public, description, fecha, url_thumb
from
(
    select 
        *,
        IF(id = @last_id, @grp_rn := @grp_rn + 1, @grp_rn := 1) as grp_rn
    from 
    (
        SELECT  cn.*, o.url_thumb
        FROM collection_names as cn LEFT JOIN collection_items as ci ON ci.collection_id=cn.id
             LEFT JOIN objects as o ON o.ID=ci.object_id
        WHERE cn.public=1
        ORDER BY cn.fecha DESC
        LIMIT 0, 20
    ) as t cross join (select @grp_rn := 0, @last_id := NULL) param
    order by t.id
) as t2
where t2.grp_rn <=4;
```

Comment: I get the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '<all column name list of collection_names>, url_thumb
(
    select 
        *,
 ' at line 1

Comment: Hi, I have edited the post and included the table definition of collection_names.

Comment: Well, now the error is here: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select 
        *,
        IF(id = last_id, grp_rn := grp_rn + 1, grp_rn := ' at line 3

Comment: Now the query works but it returns more than 4 rows per collection_name. I will try to see if I can mend it. I will let you know.